# Can we make arrays or multidimensional arrays of sprites in SFML 2.1/C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

My question is very simple. Can we make an array of sprites or images in SFML. For example:

```
int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Consider index number one, two and three are three different images. 
How can we do it? Can anyone explain with some code example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we make an array of sprites in SFML/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933134/can-we-make-an-array-of-sprites-in-sfml-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

```
sf::Sprite array[10] = { ... }
```